# Should [live-view] should be renamed to [live-preview]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[live-view](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-view) is not a thing. [live-preview](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-preview) is a thing! Let's rename it properly.

Comment: Makes sense, wish granted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks Matt!!

Comment: Now you know how to bypass those f**king limits :D